# for "pubsub.stream.listen(print, onDone: (){print('done')}). " , the "onDone:" never work

Tags: dart, flutter

the onDone:(){print('done')} never worked when get a message from redis.

```
import 'package:dartis/dartis.dart' as redis show PubSub;

void main() async {
  final pubsub = await redis.PubSub.connect<String, 
String>('redis://localhost:6379');

// Subscribe to some channels and patterns
  pubsub
    ..subscribe(channel: 'dev.dart')
    ..psubscribe(pattern: 'message');

// Listen for server replies
  pubsub.stream.listen(print, onDone: (){
    print('done');
  });
```

All i want is running a custom function with the message received from redis when a new message come in.
SOS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this fragment

```
pubsub.stream.listen(print, onDone: (){
  print('done');
});
```

the first occurrence of `print` is called a tear-off and equates to:

```
pubsub.stream.listen((event) => print(event), onDone: (){
  print('done');
});
```

you should be seeing each event printed.

The `Stream` emits `MessageEvent`s - see the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/dartis/latest/dartis/MessageEvent-class.html). `MessageEvent` has properties `channel` and `message`.

Write your own function to handle an event (for example)

```
void handleEvent(MessageEvent<String, String> event) => print(event.message);
```

and use it like this

```
pubsub.stream.listen((event) => handleEvent(event), onDone: (){
  print('done');
});
```

or, re-introducing the tear-off, like this

```
pubsub.stream.listen(handleEvent, onDone: (){
  print('done');
});
```

Comment: void handleEvent(s) => print(s); should work. And i get the  
   s = MessageEvent<String, String>: {channel=message, message=hello, pattern=message} .  now ,how can i get the "hello"? all i want is hello. i am new to dart, please help!!

Comment: rather than printing `event`, print `event.message`